# NServiceBus RabbitMQ transport throws null reference exception from RabbitMqQueueCreator

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

Get a weird error Object reference not set to an instance of an object when starting the ASP.NET Web application with the bus hosted inside.

See details below.

The code:

```
busConfiguration.UseContainer<WindsorBuilder>(c => c.ExistingContainer(container));
busConfiguration.ConfigureTransport();
busConfiguration.Transactions().Enable();
busConfiguration.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();
busConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
busConfiguration.PurgeOnStartup(false);
busConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

Bus.Create(busConfiguration).Start();
```

The Stack trace:

```
    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.]   
NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ.RabbitMqQueueCreator.CreateQueueIfNecessary(Address
address, String account) in

    C:\BuildAgent\work\ef98ad7376e3379a\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\RabbitMqQueueCreator.cs:15
NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueuesCreator.Install(String identity,
Configure config) in

    c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Queuing\QueuesCreator.cs:36
NServiceBus.Features.Starter.Run(Configure config) in

    c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Installation\InstallationSupport.cs:75
NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in

    c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:125
NServiceBus.Bus.Create(BusConfiguration configuration) in

    c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Bus.cs:19   
Workopolis.CandidateSourcing.Web.WindsorInstallers.NServiceBusInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer
container, IConfigurationStore store) in

    c:\work\CobraGit\CandidateSourcing\Web\WindsorInstallers\NServiceBusInstaller.cs:46
Castle.Windsor.Installer.AssemblyInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer
container, IConfigurationStore store) +229   
Castle.Windsor.Installer.CompositeInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer
container, IConfigurationStore store) +114   
Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[]
installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope) +165   
Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[]
installers) +227
```

Any ideas what is going on ?

Comment: The ConnectionManager is null for some reason inside RabbitMqQueueCreator class and the exception is thrown at line 15: `using (var connection = ConnectionManager.GetAdministrationConnection())`

Comment: I assume your config contains `configuration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();`? Can you provide the versions of NServiceBus, NServiceBus.RabbitMq and NServiceBus.CastleWindsor you're using? Also, do you get the same exception when not providing an existing container?